# How do I determine an acceptable $F_0$ value in sterilization?

Tags: microbiology, sterilisation

Here's a sample question:

> The sterilization process using moist heat is used to kill *B.stearothermophilus* by heating to 115 degrees C and holding it for 30 mins.
>
> For *B.stearthermophilus*, it is given that $D_{115} = 11$minutes and z=10 degrees C.
>   Determine the sterilization process equivalent time at 121 degrees C. Is this an acceptable $F_0$ value ?

By using formula $F_0 = \Delta(t) \cdot L$

I found $F_0 = 7.5$minutes.

How do I know what is the acceptable $F_0$ value? I've been told it's 15minutes. Is it 15 mins for ALL sterilization methods or is there a method to calculate this regulatory requirement of $F_0 = 15$ ?